# Running multiple sub shell script files from main shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a main shell script file `m1.sh` and another two script files `s1.sh` and `s2.sh`.

here i am running `s1.sh` and `s2.sh` from `m1.sh`.
But the problem is `s2.sh` starts running only after `s1.sh` runs completely.

`m1.sh` looks like below

```
$cat m1.sh
#!/bin/bash
./s1.sh 
./s2.sh
```

How can i run `s2.sh` when `s1.sh` starts running(i dont want to wait until `s1.sh` completes)

Answer (score 0):

You can put start them as backgroud process, like

```
#!/bin/bash
./s1.sh &
./s2.sh &

wait       # wait for all background processes to complete

for logfile in ./s1.log ./s2.log
do
    ... process "${logfile}" as needed
done
```

Comment: is there any other way, if i run in background how can i find the logs ?

Comment: Update the question with problem that you want to solve

Comment: @kiran - answer updated with one method of processing the log files once the background processes complete; you **do** know the names of the log files, right?  how does your current code *'find the logs'*?

Comment: @kofemann - feel free to (re)edit as you prefer; I couldn't see the benefit of creating a new/separate answer that merely built on your answer